# Parsing JSON in node.js gives an Error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

My Node.js application reads a string, containing JSON data, from a Python backend using `GET` method. Sometimes when I use `JSON.parse()` and refresh the page after it succeeds, it gives an `Unexpected token ,` error.

```
[
      {
       "postid":"c4jgud85mhs658sg4hn94jmd75s67w8r",
       "email":"someone@gmail.com",
       "post":"hello world",
       "comment":[]
      },
      {
       "postid":"c4jgud85mhs658sg4hn94jmd75s67w8r",
       "email":"someone@gmail.com",
       "post":"hello world",
       "comment":[]
      }
]
```

By `console.log`ging the JSON object, I was able to verify that it only prints the object partially (meaning that only a part of the object was passed) when it gives the error - for example:

```
4hn94jmd75s67w8r",
       "email":"someone@gmail.com",
       "post":"hello world",
       "comment":[]
      }
]
```

or

```
[
      {
       "postid":"c4jgud85mhs658sg
```

In node.js, Im only using

`var data = JSON.parse(resJSON); //resJSON is the variable containing the JSON`

Comment: That might be because the JSON is invalid: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: I've checked my json file in the browser..its valid

Comment: You're missing a double quote at the end of `comment` in the first object.

Comment: Can you share the Node.js code that handles the response of the `GET` request?

Comment: Please share relevant code, as well as the full error message; "Invalid token" must precede something like "expected xx instead of yy"

Comment: Btw, is that an array with two identical objects in it?

Comment: @GuiImamura it says ```Unexpected token ,```...its a bunch of JSON data in that format...they are not identical.

Comment: They look identical in your example. Apparently, something is causing your object to lose data somewhere. We would like to check your code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's succeeding "*sometimes*," I'd suspect you're parsing the response as the `'data'` arrives, such as:

```
http.get('...', function (res) {
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
    });
});
```

This will work if the response is sent all at once. But, it can also be divided into multiple chunks that will be received through multiple `'data'` events.

To handle chunked responses, you'll want to combine the `chunk`s back together and `parse` the response as a whole once the stream has come to an [`'end'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end).

```
http.get('...', function (res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    });
});
```